# Make popup opening after a while even if the user is navigating to other page

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, popup

I need a bit of help with this javascript code.

I have this code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    if (document.cookie.indexOf('visited=true') == -1) {
    var fifteenDays = 1000*60*60*24*1;
    var expires = new Date((new Date()).valueOf() + fifteenDays);
    document.cookie = "visited=true;expires=" + expires.toUTCString();
    window.setTimeout(
function() {
    jQuery.colorbox({href:"/popup.htm", open:true, iframe:false, innerWidth:600, innerHeight:490}); 
        },

30000 )}});
```

It's supposed to open a popup after 30 seconds, one time per day. The issue is that the popup it's opening after 30 seconds on stay on a page. It's there any way to make it to open after 30 seconds even if the client navigate to other page ? So, if the user stay 15 seconds on a page and 15 on another, getting the popup.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fundamental issue to overcome here is passing the 'state' between pages. Since you're already using cookies in your example, we'll work with that. You need to set a session cookie with the time the user has been on the site (initially 0). You'd then need to 'poll' the cookie once every so often (every 5 seconds maybe) to update the total time on site count, and read it back. If it's 30 seconds or more, fire the popup.

So instead of using:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    // open alert box
}, 30000);
```

You'd do something like:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    // Increment 'time-on-site' cookie value by 5000
    // Then, if 'time-on-site' cookie value >= 30000, fire popup
}, 5000);
```

**UPDATE**
Of course, this requires a lot more back-and-forth to the server, as you need to communicate the updated value every 5 seconds.

Comment: That means a "ping"-like request each 5 seconds. Lot of cookies and tons of coding, right ? If so, I will give up with this part and only reduce the 30 seconds timeout to 15 seconds. Thanks for the explanation and reply.

Comment: Yes if you want to maintain state by passing back to the server. Although I guess you can simplify it by just setting the `document.cookie` which will exist for that domain across page loads. The other way would involve calculating time offset from first visit on every page load, which would be a bit gnarly.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes.**

But it's not possible using `document.cookie`.

You would need to use server-side cookies or HTML local storage/session storage.

Something like, `Response.SetCookie("Visited", true)`. I don't know what you're using as back end.

Comment: It's php, html on an apache server. Sounds pretty complicated to be done, right ? Too many cookies...

Comment: One-per-client, per-page. But that's not much if you really need it. Another way is to have an identity cookie that identifies the user and log the visits in your database. Accordingly, you can render those scripts onto the page.

Answer (score 1):

No way man. Once the page is unloaded you cannot do anything else. You need to use other resources on server (cookies, session, etc..) to check if the window is already displayed or not.

Comment: The cookie part is easy to be done. The hardest part is making that cookie register at which second the user left the first page and continue counting from that instead reseting the counter to 0. I guess there is too much effort for such a stupid "feature".

Comment: I think there is not easy way to do this, although on server side could be a little more easier (with a less accurate time-counting). But you will need at least 1 or 2 session/cookie states and check on every page load if it's "time" to display the dialog.

Comment: @demlasjr: Yes, smells of over-engineering. :)

Comment: @RobinMaben guess it's time to give up :)

Comment: @demlasjr: I would say you could put that time and effort into another feature in your application of higher priority(and usefulness to the user). I'm sure there are. :)